# What does the 'ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending' error mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending. To resolve
>   this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
>
> Extracted source (around line #392): 390 391       def
>   check_pending!(connection = Base.connection) 392         raise
>   ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if
>   ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection) 393       end 394
>   395       def load_schema_if_pending!
>
> Rails.root: /Users/checkkdahustle/Desktop/Full Sail/25. Advanced
>   Server-Side Languages/ASL/APP_2/Project2/ShoeDeals
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace activerecord (4.2.5)
>   lib/active_record/migration.rb:392:in `check_pending!' activerecord
>   (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in
>   call' activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`
>   **run_callbacks**' activesupport (4.2.5)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks' actionpack (4.2.5)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.2.5)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>   web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.5)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' railties
>   (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (4.2.5)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' railties (4.2.5)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call' actionpack (4.2.5)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call' activesupport (4.2.5)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`
>   call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.2.5)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call' railties (4.2.5)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call' railties (4.2.5)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in`service'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`
>   run'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in
>   `block in start_thread'

Comment: Have you tried what it's telling you to do? `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: I just ran the line that @dwenzel suggested and this popped up: NoMethodError in Shoe#index...... im looking over my code now

Comment: I would suggest adding this information to your question, including the full new error.  It's always good to provide as much information as you can when you pose a question here in Stack Overflow; as opposed to just pasting the full error and stack trace with no context.

Comment: ok ill do that. thanks@dwenzel

Answer (score 6):

Look at the very first line of the trace you posted:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

That exactly is what it means:

> Migrations are pending

So, you have some migrations that are yet to be run which means your schema is not up to date.

To fix it, all you have to do is run the pending migrations

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If you have already created the database and it was working before now. If this is a new app on your machine, the database doesn't exist yet. You have to first create a database and then run the migration as follow:

```
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: my database works just fine. I just ran the line that @dwenzel suggested and this popped up:  NoMethodError in Shoe#index...... 'bundle exec rake db:migrate' would be the answer at this point would it?

Comment: `NoMethodError`... which method was that pointing to from your error trace?

Comment: it points to my index.html.erb but i dont see the problem. this is the exact line it show:

Comment: app/views/shoe/index.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_shoe_index_html_erb___4223921823397208640_70151805921720'

Comment: and what is on that line? btw: this has almost nothing to do with the initial db migration error. It is something entirely different. so, what is on line 13 of your `index.html.erb` view file?

Comment: the line its looking at looks like this:     <% @shoes.each do |shoe| %>

Comment: can you paste the whole stack trace?

Comment: NoMethodError in Shoe#index
Showing /Users/checkkdahustle/Desktop/Full Sail/25. Advanced Server-Side Languages/Orcun Tagtekin/ASL/APP_2/Project2/ShoeDeals/app/views/shoe/index.html.erb where line #13 raised:       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: hmm... interesting. and can you show the `index` method in your controller?

Answer (score 2):

bundle exec rake db:migrate this will give us solution

Answer (score 2):

`rake db:migrate` command will runs migrations for the current env that have not run yet. if you are on development env you don't need to specify any env . From below command you can run all pending migrations which are not run yet

**For Rails version > 5**

```
rails db:migrate
```

**For Rails version < 5**

```
rake db:migrate
```

**Extra stuff**

if you want to check which migrations are run and which are pending you can use bolow command

```
rails db:migrate:status
```

Comment: Good call on `rails db:migrate:status` , was useful for  me to find out which migration was out of sync

Answer (score 0):

If all the solutions don't work for you kill your rails server and start it again this worked for me as i ran `rails db:migrate:status` and found no pending migrations